# error while trying to stepdown mongodb replica set

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

Setup:
1 primary, 3 secondaries and 1 arbiter (All 5 are running.)

When I'm doing a stepDown() in primary, getting the below error in the shell -

```
m101:PRIMARY> rs.stepDown() 
2017-06-07T15:01:21.357 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: error doing query: failed: network error while attempting to run command 'replSetStepDown' on host '127.0.0.1:27018'  :  
DB.prototype.runCommand@src/mongo/shell/db.js:132:1 
DB.prototype.adminCommand@src/mongo/shell/db.js:150:16  
rs.stepDown@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:1261:12
@(shell):1:1 
2017-06-07T15:01:21.360 I NETWORK  [thread1] trying reconnect to 127.0.0.1:27018 (127.0.0.1) failed
2017-06-07T15:01:21.361 I NETWORK  [thread1] reconnect 127.0.0.1:27018 (127.0.0.1) ok
m101:SECONDARY>
```

Note that the primary changed to secondary in the end. But why I'm getting this error, "failed: network error" here?

Below is the section from the log file of the primary which was stepped down -

```
2017-06-07T15:01:22.170 I REPL     [replication-5] Restarting oplog query due to error: InterruptedDueToReplStateChange: operation was interrupted. Last fetched optime (with hash): { ts: Timestamp 1496827872000|1, t: 2 }[-3490433912114125886]. Restarts remaining: 3
2017-06-07T15:01:22.170 I REPL     [replication-5] Scheduled new oplog query Fetcher source: localhost:27018 database: local query: { find: "oplog.rs", filter: { ts: { $gte: Timestamp 1496827872000|1 } }, tailable: true, oplogReplay: true, awaitData: true, maxTimeMS: 60000, term: 2 } query metadata: { $replData: 1, $oplogQueryData: 1, $ssm: { $secondaryOk: true } } active: 1 timeout: 65000ms shutting down?: 0 first: 1 firstCommandScheduler: RemoteCommandRetryScheduler request: RemoteCommand 159434 -- target:localhost:27018 db:local cmd:{ find: "oplog.rs", filter: { ts: { $gte: Timestamp 1496827872000|1 } }, tailable: true, oplogReplay: true, awaitData: true, maxTimeMS: 60000, term: 2 } active: 1 callbackHandle.valid: 1 callbackHandle.cancelled: 0 attempt: 1 retryPolicy: RetryPolicyImpl maxAttempts: 1 maxTimeMillis: -1ms
2017-06-07T15:01:22.173 W REPL     [rsBackgroundSync] Fetcher stopped querying remote oplog with error: InvalidSyncSource: Sync source's last applied OpTime { ts: Timestamp 1496827872000|1, t: 2 } is not greater than our last fetched OpTime { ts: Timestamp 1496827872000|1, t: 2 }. Choosing new sync source.
2017-06-07T15:01:22.176 I REPL     [rsBackgroundSync] could not find member to sync from
2017-06-07T15:01:22.180 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] Member localhost:27018 is now in state SECONDARY
2017-06-07T15:01:27.335 I REPL     [SyncSourceFeedback] SyncSourceFeedback error sending update to localhost:27018: InvalidSyncSource: Sync source was cleared. Was localhost:27018
2017-06-07T15:01:29.879 I -        [conn2] end connection 127.0.0.1:59400 (5 connections now open)
2017-06-07T15:01:30.899 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:64421 #28 (5 connections now open)
2017-06-07T15:01:30.899 I NETWORK  [conn28] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:64421 conn28: { driver: { name: "NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication", version: "3.4.4" }, os: { type: "Windows", name: "Microsoft Windows 8", architecture: "x86_64", version: "6.2 (build 9200)" } }
2017-06-07T15:01:30.917 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:64425 #29 (6 connections now open)
2017-06-07T15:01:30.920 I NETWORK  [conn29] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:64425 conn29: { driver: { name: "NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication", version: "3.4.4" }, os: { type: "Windows", name: "Microsoft Windows 8", architecture: "x86_64", version: "6.2 (build 9200)" } }
2017-06-07T15:01:30.927 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:64428 #30 (7 connections now open)
2017-06-07T15:01:30.928 I NETWORK  [conn30] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:64428 conn30: { driver: { name: "NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication", version: "3.4.4" }, os: { type: "Windows", name: "Microsoft Windows 8", architecture: "x86_64", version: "6.2 (build 9200)" } }
2017-06-07T15:01:31.561 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] Starting an election, since we've seen no PRIMARY in the past 10000ms
2017-06-07T15:01:31.562 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] conducting a dry run election to see if we could be elected
2017-06-07T15:01:31.563 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] VoteRequester(term 2 dry run) received a no vote from localhost:27018 with reason "candidate's term is lower than mine"; response message: { term: 3, voteGranted: false, reason: "candidate's term is lower than mine", ok: 1.0 }
2017-06-07T15:01:31.563 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] not running for primary, we have been superceded already
2017-06-07T15:01:32.183 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] Member localhost:27019 is now in state PRIMARY
2017-06-07T15:01:32.185 I REPL     [rsBackgroundSync] sync source candidate: localhost:27019
2017-06-07T15:01:32.186 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Connecting to localhost:27019
2017-06-07T15:01:33.198 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Successfully connected to localhost:27019, took 1012ms (1 connections now open to localhost:27019)
```

Trying to understand what's happening here. Any leads would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. When a primary steps down it drops all connections, including your active connection in the `mongo` shell. The `mongo` shell then reestablishes the connection (as per the "trying reconnect" message).

The [`rs.stepDown()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.stepDown/) documentation could perhaps be clearer on this point with an example of the shell output, but the relevant description is:

> Upon successful stepdown, rs.stepDown() forces all clients currently connected to the database to disconnect. This helps ensure that the clients maintain an accurate view of the replica set.
>
> Because the disconnect includes the connection used to run the command, you cannot retrieve the return status of the command if the command completes successfully; i.e. you can only retrieve the return status of the command if it errors. When running the command in a script, the script should account for this behavior.